TYPO3 Extbase Extension with bidirectional mm-relation messed up language relation fields
System: TYPO3 11.5.36 with own expansion to display news and persons. Running on Apache with PHP 7.4.33 and MySQL 5.5.5-10.5.23-MariaDB-0+deb11u1
Setup: We have a person model and a news model.
The news have a property authors and the persons the property news.
Problem: On translated news records the authors will only show up, if we save the news. But when we save the person, the author is only shown in the default language, not in the translated language.
While saving the news record, we have a entry in MM-table for the German and English news with the German ids of the persons. But when we save the person, we have two German news-ids with a German and English person id. It's flipped around. How to avoid this?
There is no fancy stuff going on in the controller action or in the fluid template. We can't figure out, how to configure the property, or how to write a query to address this issue. Are we missing something here?
Details
In the backend, we create a new news and assign an existing person as author. Then translate the news (the person is already translated). Then we see the authors on the news page in the frontend for the default language (German) and the translated version (English). This is working!
Then when saving the person record without changing any data, the translated record won't show the author anymore.
Example (for allowLanguageSynchronization = true):



table
language
uid




person
0 (ger)
1


person
1 (eng)
2


news
0 (ger)
10


news
1 (eng)
11



MM-Table looks like this while saving on news:



uid_local (news)
uid_foreign (person)




10
1


11
1



MM-Table looks like this while saving on person:



uid_local (news)
uid_foreign (person)




10
1


10
2



// TCA from news:

'authors' => array(
            'exclude' => 0,
            'displayCond' => 'FIELD:sys_language_uid:<=:0',
            'l10n_mode' => 'exclude',
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:fgsnews/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_fgsnews_domain_model_news.authors',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_fgspersons_domain_model_person',
                'foreign_table_where' => "
                    AND tx_fgspersons_domain_model_person.sys_language_uid in (-1,0)
                    AND tx_fgspersons_domain_model_person.hidden = 0
                    ORDER BY tx_fgspersons_domain_model_person.last_name ASC
                ",
                'MM' => 'tx_fgsnews_news_person_mm',
                'autoSizeMax' => 30,
                'maxitems' => 9999,
                'multiple' => 0,
                'suggestOptions' => [
                    'default' => [
                        'searchWholePhrase' => 1,
                        'additionalSearchFields' => 'first_name,last_name'
                    ]
                ],
                'behaviour' => [
                    'allowLanguageSynchronization' => true,
                ],
            ),
        )

/// TCA from person:

'news' => array(
        'displayCond' => 'FIELD:sys_language_uid:<=:0',
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'News',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_fgsnews_domain_model_news',
            'foreign_table_where' => "
                    AND tx_fgsnews_domain_model_news.sys_language_uid IN (-1,0)
                    AND tx_fgsnews_domain_model_news.hidden = 0
                    ORDER BY tx_fgsnews_domain_model_news.starttime Desc
                ",
            'MM' => 'tx_fgsnews_news_person_mm',
            'MM_opposite_field' => 'authors',
            'autoSizeMax' => 30,
            'maxitems' => 999,
            'multiple' => 0,
            'suggestOptions' => [
                    'default' => [
                        'searchWholePhrase' => 1
                    ]
                ],
            'l10n_mode' => 'exclude',
            'behaviour' => [
                'allowLanguageSynchronization' => true,
            ],
        ),
    )

// News Controller - Action:

public function showAction(News $news) {
        $this->view->assign('news', $news);

        $authorNames = [];
        $authors = $news->getAuthors();
        $validAuthors = array();

        foreach ($authors as $author) {
            $authorNames[] = $author->getFullname();
            $personType = $author->getType();
            if ($personType != null && $personType->getVisibility() == 2) {
                $validAuthors[] = $author;
            }
        }

        $this->view->assign('authors', $validAuthors);
    }

// Fluid Template

<f:if condition="{authors}">
    <article class="frame frame-mask_text frame-width-85 action-show">
        <div class="frame-content">
            <div class="bodytext person-contacts">
                <f:for each="{authors}" as="person">
                    <f:render partial="Person/Contact" arguments="{person: person}" />
                </f:for>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</f:if>

We tried different settings with l10n_mode and allowLanguageSynchronization, but it ended up in the same results not showing the English records.
If we save the news, everything is working fine. But if we save the person the uid's in the mm-table get flipped around which causes the problem. We need it to be persistent, so that we can handle and edit the associations bidirectional in both records.
If allowLanguageSynchronization is set to false however the mm-Table behaves a little bit different. While saving the news its still the same as described above. But if saving the author, only the record for the default language is saved in the mm-table. If there was a record for the translated record from saving the news, it gets deleted.

did you try to remove AND tx_fgsnews_domain_model_news.sys_language_uid IN (-1,0) from the foreign_table_where for the person table?

Hi David. Thanks for your suggestion. We have set this on purpose, because this filters the selection in the multiple selectbox in the backend to show only the entries of the default language. If you remove it, then you have all language versions in the selection which is not what we need. It would confuse the editor if there would be two versions of the same news to choose from. Or do we get here something wrong?

my assumption was that it's filtering undesired, but I'm not sure about it. Trying it takes 5 minutes, so it doesn't hurt, but probably you're right.

i tried your suggestion. There was no diference in the behaviour regarding the problem. But in the backend the multiple selectbox had both, the english and german news as possible selections.

I can't find anyone that has the same problem. Should this not be a normal usecase? What do we get wrong here? We only want to disable the localization and keep the authors in sync with the default language. This bidirectional approach is nessassary, because we need the sorting of the news for each author. But why is this not working as it should be?

actually it sound to me like you have two mm tables for the same connection, but your TCA looks correct though

So you could  look if a table named tx_fgsnews_person_news_mm exists in your database

Hi David thank you for your suggestion. I can confirm that there is no additional table tx_fgsnews_person_news_mm. The Values i described in the example are really changing in the tx_fgsnews_news_person_mm. So both sides save in the same table, but they switch the translated record ids. We also tried allowLanguageSynchronization = true, but that don't change the behaviour.

I suspect your problems might arise from the multiple option, where the documentation says that the boolean option MM_hasUidField "If the multiple property is set with MM relations you must set this value to true and include a UID field. Otherwise, sorting and removing relations will be buggy.", it's just not said how to do it.

See https://github.com/TYPO3-Documentation/TYPO3CMS-Reference-TCA/issues/1054

Thinking about the relation news <-> authors, I don't see a sense to use the multiple option, so you could disable it, or have to find out how to "include a UID field". So it's an interesting flaw in the documentation, but I think you don't need the feature here.

Hi David, thank you for your response and input. You are absolutely right, that the "multiple" flag is not necessary here and was not intended. I changed and edited in the process quite some config and in the live database the multiple flag was never set and always on 0.
Unfortunately it was left over in the testing process for this topic. Sad to say, this was not the problem and the behaviour is still the same.

as far as  I remember the configuration below the key wizards doesn't exist anymore in this kind, so you could delete it including the key.

See this deprecation notice with migration instructions.It's advised to look up the right notation in the documentation for v11, as it might have changed again perhaps.

Hi David, you are right with the wizards-section. I have changed it, but this does not affect the described behaviour.
I tested around quite a bit now again. If i set allowLanguageSynchronization to true, then the described switches in the mm-Table will happen. But if it is set to false then saving the news is still correct (creating a record for DE and EN in the MM-table) and saving on the author side, only die DE record will be saved in the MM-table and the EN record will be deleted. This is different from what i described earlier. I must have missed this fact in the database.
